# Restar años a fechas y filtrar resultados

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla `personal` en donde registro los datos del empleado y la fecha de contratación de este; lo siguiente que quiero hacer es filtrar los empleados en base a la fecha de contratación, si tiene mas de 5 años en la empresa, desde la fecha de contratación, queda descartado, y si tiene menos de 5 años desde la fecha de contratación entonces será seleccionado, tomando como dato el año actual (2019) menos el año de la fecha de contratación del empleado.

Por ejemplo: **2019 (Año actual) - 2009 (año de fecha de contratación) = 10 años, es decir, no será seleccionado**.

Segundo ejemplo : **2019 (Año actual) - 2015 (año de contratación) = 4 años, es decir, será seleccionado**.

He aquí mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_contratacion, CURDATE()) AS años_transcurridos from personal;
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Efectivamente, me devuelve la diferencia de años entre el año actual y la fecha de contratación del empleado, pero no se como implementar esto en una consulta para que me devuelva los datos de todos los empleados que cumplan la condición anteriormente mencionada.

Comment: Si entendí bien lo que buscas, sería algo así: `select * from personal where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_contratacion, CURDATE()) <=5`

Comment: Excelente, es lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Por qué no pruebas haciendo uso de `WHERE`?

Esta función nos ayudará a realizar un filtrado de los resultados con base en una condición, en este caso evaluamos el número de años que nos devuelve `años_transcurridos` donde si es menor a 5 entonces tome los resultados en el `SELECT` y si no que los descarte.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_contratacion, CURDATE()) AS años_transcurridos 
from personal
WHERE años_transcurridos < 5;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizas `having` en una consulta que no tiene `group by`? Pregunto, porque no le hallo mucho sentido, debiera ser un `where`.

Comment: Hola @jachguate, debido (aunque es obvio que puedo estar equivocado), a que sabía que si no existe un agrupamiento de valores en común, entonces `HAVING` actúa similar a `WHERE`

Comment: Solo en el caso de mysql. Eso está totalmente fuera del estándar.

Comment: gracias por la aclaración @jachguate lo desconocía